# Finding the maximum value

Tags: trigonometry

Find the maximum value of: $\sin(c-b)+\sin(a-c)+\sin(a-b)$ I think the maximum value will be $1$ when $c-b=π/2$ and $a-c=π/2$, but how can we prove this?

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $\sin(a-b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)-\cos(a)sin(b)$.

Then, you can expand your expression to find:

$\sin(c)\cos(b)-\cos(c)\sin(b)+\sin(a)\cos(c)-\cos(a)\sin(c)+\sin(a)\cos(b)-\cos(a)\sin(b)$.

Do you see where I am going with this?

Comment: actually that was the original expression I factored it all down to that...

Comment: Ok. Then we would like to minimize the negative terms and maximize those positive terms. Can you see a way we can do that?